# Azure Data Factory - Rerun Failed Pipeline Against Azure SQL Table With Differential Date Filter

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to keep an Azure SQL DB in sync with an on-prem DB. The on-prem DB is read only and the direction is one-way, from the Azure SQL DB to the on-prem DB.

My source table in the Azure SQL Cloud DB is quite large (10's of millions of rows) so I have the pipeline set to use an UPSERT (merge, trying to create a differential merge). I am using a filter on the Source table and the and the Filter Query has a WHERE condition that looks like this:

```
[HistoryDate] >= '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' )}' 
AND [HistoryDate] < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowEnd, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' )}'
```

The HistoryDate column is auto-maintained in the source table with a getUTCDate() type approach. New records will always get a higher value and be included in the WHERE condition.

This works well, but here is my question: I am testing on my local machine before deploying to the client. When I am not working, my laptop hibernates and the pipeline rightfully fails because my local SQL Instance is "offline" during that run. When I move this to production this should not be an issue (computer hibernating), but what happens if the clients connection is temporarily lost (i.e, the client loses internet for a time)? Because my pipeline has a WHERE condition on the source to reduce the table size upsert to a practical number, any failure would result in a loss of any data created during that 5 minute window.

A failed pipeline can be rerun, but the run time would be different at that moment in time and I would effectively miss the block of records that would have been picked up if the pipeline had been run on time. pipeline().parameters.windowStart and pipeline().parameters.windowEnd will now be different.

As an FYI, I have this running every 5 minutes to keep the local copy in sync as close to real-time as possible.

Am I approaching this correctly? I'm sure others have this scenario and it's likely I am missing something obvious. :-)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but to potentially help others in the future, it seems there was a better way to deal with this.

ADF offers a "Metadata-driven Copy Task" utility/wizard on the home screen that creates a pipeline. When I used it, it offers a "Delta Load" option for tables which takes a "Watermark". The watermark is a column for an incrementing IDENTITY column, increasing date or timestamp, etc. At the end of the wizard, it allows you to download a script that builds a table and corresponding stored procedure that maintains the values of each parameters after each run. For example, if I wanted my delta load to be based on an IDENTITY column, it stores the value of the max value of a particular pipeline run. The next time a run happens (trigger), it uses this as the MIN value (minus 1) and the current MAX value of the IDENTITY column to get the added records since the last run.

I was going to approach things this way, but it seems like ADF already does this heavy lifting for us. :-)